# How to extract lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

```
'''
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
find 1
'''
key = 1
x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[key]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

#len(x) -> 1
```

Actually my question is simple, but i couldn't solve this problem... What should i use to solve it, i mean should i use recrusive functions or for loop ???

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(x)):
            for _ in range(len(x)):
                for ...
```

Comment: What is your question though? What does "extract list" mean?

Comment: "this problem" what problem? You just posted a bunch of nonsense code, not a problem.

Comment: What is a recrusive function?

Comment: take a look https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as follow using `more_itertools`

```py
import more_itertools

key = 1
x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[key]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

flattened_list = list(more_itertools.collapse(x))

print(flattened_list) # [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-recursive approach for your current structure:

```py
def extract_list(l: list):
    while True:
        l = l.pop()
        if not isinstance(l, list):
            return l


x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
print(extract_list(x))  # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with type check

```
key = 1
x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[key]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

def find_key(array):
    if type(array) is list:
        return find_key(array[0])
    return array

print(find_key(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a couple ways but here's a solution using recursion:

```
x = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

def find_num(l):
    if isinstance(inner := l[0], list):
        return find_num(inner)
    return inner

print(find_num(x))
```

---

```
1
```